# Spark calculate the percentage of appearances of words

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a PairRDD like this (word, wordCount). Now, I need to calculate for each word the percentage of appearances on the total of the words count, obtaining a final PairRDD like this (word, (wordCount, percentage)).

I tried with:

```
val pairs = .... .cache() // (word, wordCount)
val wordsCount = pairs.map(_._2).reduce(_+_)
pairs.map{
        case (word, count) => (word, (count, BigDecimal(count/wordsCount.toDouble * 100).setScale(3, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble))
      }
```

But it does not seem very efficient (i'm a beginner). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using `keys.count()`? Shouldn't you take the word count into account when calculating the percentage?

Comment: You are right! I corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calculating `wordsCount`, `map(_._2).reduce(_ + _)` is more idiomatically expressed by the `aggregate` method:

```scala
val pairs = .... .cache() // (word, wordCount)
val wordsCount = pairs.aggregate(0)((sum, pair) => sum + pair._2, _ + _)
```

The first argument is the initial total count, which should be zero. The next two arguments are in a separate argument list, and are executed for each member of your *pair RDD*. The first of this second set of arguments (`(sum, pair) => sum + pair._2`, termed the *sequence operator*) adds each value in a partition to the current sum value for that partition; while the second (`_ + _`, termed the *combination operator*) combines counts from different partitions. The main benefit is that this operation is performed in parallel, by each partition, across the data, and guarantees no expensive *repartitioning* (a.k.a. *shuffling*) of that data. (Repartitioning occurs when data needs to be transferred between nodes in the cluster, and is very slow due to network communication.)

While `aggregate` does not affect partitioning of the data, you should note that, if your data is partitioned, a `map` operation will remove the partitioning scheme - because of the possibility that the *keys* in the *pair RDD* might get changed by the transformation. This might resulting in subsequent repartitioning if you perform any further transformations on the result of a `map` transformation. That said, a `map` operation followed by a `reduce` shouldn't result in repartitioning, but might be slightly less efficient because of the extra step (but not hugely so).

If you're concerned that the total word count might overflow an `Int` type, you could use a `BigInt` instead:

```scala
val wordsCount = pairs.aggregate(BigInt(0))((sum, pair) => sum + pair._2, _ + _)
```

As for producing a *pair RDD* with the word counts and percentages as the value, you should use `mapValues` instead of `map`. Again `mapValues` will retain any existing partitioning scheme (because it guarantees that the *keys* will not get changed by the transformation), while `map` will remove it. Furthermore, `mapValues` is simpler in that you do not need to process *key* values:

```scala
pairs.mapValues(c => (c, c * 100.0 / wordsCount))
```

That should provide sufficient accuracy for your purposes. I would only worry about rounding, and using `BigDecimal`, when retrieving and outputting values. However, if you really do need that, your code would look like this:

```scala
pairs.mapValues{c =>
  (c, BigDecimal(c * 100.0 / wordsCount).setScale(3, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A very detailed answer.